# Is there a way to stream data into GIT instead of passing in file names?

Tags: c#, java, c, git

We want to stream documents that do not exist in a file system (they are in a database) into GIT. Since there are thousands of documents, we dont want to create them on disk.

We know that we can stream documents out of GIT using the GIT Blob classes.

We want to pragmatically provide tree/path and filename and any other attributes, but the file will not actually exist. GIT itself streams data into itself at some point (when it reads the file) and stores file attribute data somehow.

I know how to add files in GIT, I want to interface using a stream instead.

Is this possible using C, C# or Java?

Comment: You may want to clarify what you are actually asking. Are you talking about the GIT version control system? Is so, what do you mean when you say 'stream data into git'? And what could a version control system do with a file that doesn't exist?

Comment: Really? -1? For asking a question? How about explaining your thinking, since you have no basis for understanding mine as I purposely did not post it, opting instead to post a technical question, expecting a technical answer. (Since I cannot delete comments - your comment seems to have showed up only after I posted my comment... I will address your question)

Comment: There is absolutely nothing wrong with this question. I'll refine your last sentence, which is probably what some people might be objecting to.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `hash-object`.

```
gitid=$(echo hello world | git hash-object -w --stdin)
```

This will set `gitid` to the git id of a new blob object based on the output of the `echo` command.

You can then use `git update-index` to add an index entry using this blob and `commit` to make a commit object containing the new blob in your git repository.

```
git update-index --add --cacheinfo 100644 "$gitid" new-blob.txt

git commit -m "new commit"
```

Answer (score 3):

You could also create the objects "by hand", by creating the objects and trees from your code. Here is a video of GitHub's Tom Preston-Werner describing the structure: http://sea.ucar.edu/event/unlocking-secrets-git I don't know if that's the way to go for you, but it's an option

Comment: This video was fantastic. Thank you.